# What is $X^TX$ called where $X$ is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

With $X$ being a matrix, is there a general name for the expression $X^TX$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) (or Gramian matrix)